# Проверить кортеж на пустой элемент

Tags: python-3.x, tuple

Mожно ли как-то проверить кортеж на пустой элемент?

Например есть кортеж `a = (1,)`, у которого нет второго элемента. Как можно его проверить?

Comment: уточните вопрос - вы хотите проверить длину кортежа или то что второй элемент пустой (`None`)?

Comment: Кортеж `a = (1, )` состоит из `1` элемента. _"Пустых"_ элементов у него нет.

Comment: @MaxU да, проверить то, что второй элемент None

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вам уже написали в комментариях, `(1,)` - кортеж, состоящий из **одного** элемента, поэтому чтобы проверить *второй элемент* вам понадобится дополнительная проверка на длину кортежа:

```
if len(a) > 1 and a[1] is not None:
    # ...
```

PS в Python невозможно создать кортеж из единственного элемента, не указав после него запятую. Это плата за использование обычных скобок, которые также используются для явного указания приоритета операций.

Пример кортежа:

```
In [1]: a = (1,)

In [2]: len(a)
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: type(a)
Out[3]: tuple
```

Если мы попытаемся сделать тоже самое, но без запятой, то мы получим скалярное значение вместо кортежа:

```
In [4]: b = (1)

In [5]: type(b)
Out[5]: int       #  <--- NOTE !!!

In [6]: tuple(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-69b6b14cc30a> in <module>
----> 1 tuple(1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Со списками и множествами указывать запятую после единственного элемента не нужно:

```
In [10]: l = [1]

In [11]: type(l)
Out[11]: list

In [12]: len(l)
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: s = {1}

In [14]: type(s)
Out[14]: set

In [15]: len(s)
Out[15]: 1
```